# what does should i changed the stdin into with?

Tags: bufferedreader, readline, system.in

I need help. I'm still a beginner in Java, so my knowledge is still weak.

There's a lot of tries that I did, I still don't know why my programming build fails. Can you guys help me?

```
package act2i;

import java.io.*;
public class Act2I {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader (new
        InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        //declare variable
        String str;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the data: ");
        str = stdin.readLine();//read input that is entered by user
        
        //display an output, str value
        System.out.println("You have entered: " + str);
    }//end main()
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change "stdin" to "inData".